# SSRS counting null values

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

How can I count the number of null values using SSRS? The following expression is not working:

```
= Count(IsNothing(Feilds!.FieldName.Value))
```

This also isn't working:

```
= Count(Feilds!.FieldName.Value Is Nothing)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
=Sum(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!FieldName.Value),1,0))
```

I don’t have my copy of SSRS to hand but that should work just fine